# UTF-8 string not decoded correctly in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a text input box, within a SPA built on AngularJS, for users to add a title to a printout.  The input box is declared like this:

```
<input class="chart-title" type="text" ng-model="chartTitle" ng-change="titleChanged()"/>
```

The text box is filled with a default title provided by the server.  A user may change the title to whatever suits them.  When the title is changed, the server is updated and sends back a new title in the header of the response which then replaces the title in the box.  This works perfectly for standard ASCII type characters.

However, for unicode characters (for example àßéçøö) it does not work. The text is sent down correctly, updated on the server correctly, and returned to the SPA correctly.  The headers for the request/response are here:

```
Request URL:http://blahblahblah/api/.....&chartTitle=Instrument:%20%C3%A0%C3%9F%C3%A9%C3%A7%C3%B8%C3%B6
```

Response Headers:

```
chartTitle: Instrument: %C3%A0%C3%9F%C3%A9%C3%A7%C3%B8%C3%B6
```

The request is made using AngularJS `$http()`. As you can see the values match up (the space in the request codes out as `%20` for obvious reasons).  However, when I retrieve the header, using `headers("charttitle")`, the value I receive is `Instrument: Ã ÃÃ©Ã§Ã¸Ã¶`

The javascript bundle is declared in the index with charset utf-8:

```
<script src="/js/bundle.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

In addition the html is declared with the correct charset, it seems to me in two places within the head declaration:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

According to this website (http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) it appears that I am getting Windows1252 character encoding.  This does not make any sense.  I could, if absolutely necessary, write a horrible hack converting the utf-8 string to Windows1252 characters, but this seems a little extreme and quite error prone to me.

The effect is the same, whether on Chrome, Firefox or IE11.  The full request headers are here:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Host:blahblahblah
Origin:http://blahblahblah
Referer:http://blahblahblah/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

Is there anything I have left out?  Anything that has been forgotten?

**EDIT**

*Full response headers as requested.*

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:chartTitle
Cache-Control:private
chartTitle:Instrument: %C3%A0%C3%9F%C3%A9%C3%A7%C3%B8%C3%B6
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=PrintData.pdf
Content-Length:1391643
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Fri, 20 Jan 2017 11:19:07 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcR2l0XEVPU1xSZXZpZXdlci5XZWJcYXBpXFByaW50XGQyOTNkNjA4NWVlYzlhNTEwYjQ5YThmZGQxNjNhMjAwMWZhYTFjMGY5YzhiMzUxYzE5ZjYxYWMwYTY1OWVhMDM=?=
```

*Code around the `headers`*

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: filePath,
    params: {
        fileName: fileName
    },
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
}).success(function (data, status, headers) {
    ready();
    if (status == 200) {
        var chartTitle = headers("charttitle");
        var printoutInformation = {'chartTitle' : chartTitle, 'pdfData' : data};
        deferred.resolve(printoutInformation);
    }
    else {
        deferred.resolve(null);
    }
    }).error(function (data) {
        ready();
        console.log(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
```

**EDIT**

The `web.config` for the api also specifies utf-8:

```
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

**TL;DR**

In a text box I want to display "Instrument àßéçøö" and instead I am seeing "Instrument: Ã ÃÃ©Ã§Ã¸Ã¶"

Comment: What are the full *response* headers? Also a short but complete code sample around `headers('charttitle')` would help.

Comment: @deceze - I have edited the question to add the code sample and the full response headers.

Comment: `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` is necessary?

Comment: @Sravan - Yes, as the response is a pdf as an array of bytes

Comment: @deceze - added web.config information if that helps

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is your issue solved.

Based on this source,

[UTF-8 character debugging and its encoding and decoding](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html)

**The response you are getting is the actual charecter of the encoded utf-8 string**

So, you need to decode that inorder to get your result.

HEre is the code to do it.

```
    decoded =  decodeURIComponent('%C3%A0%C3%9F%C3%A9%C3%A7%C3%B8%C3%B6')

    console.log(decoded);

   The result is => "àßéçøö"
```

**we have to do this to get the actual string instead of UTF-8**

So, from your response you got,`Ã ÃÃ©Ã§Ã¸Ã¶`

**`decodeURIComponent(escape("Ã ÃÃ©Ã§Ã¸Ã¶")) => "àßéçøö"`**

**DEFINITION:**

### **decodeURIComponent():**

- A new string representing the decoded version of the given encoded Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component.

So , here is your method.

```
if (status == 200) {
    var original = headers("charttitle");
    var chartTitle = decodeURIComponent(escape(original));
    console.log(chartTitle);
    var printoutInformation = {'chartTitle' : chartTitle, 'pdfData' : data};
    deferred.resolve(printoutInformation);
}
```

Now, you will get the headers same as you send.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sravan.  However, I do not want "%C3%83%20%C3%83%C3%83%C2%A9%C3%83%C2%A7%C3%83%C2%B8%C3%83%C2%B6".  What I want is the original characters: "Instrument: àßéçøö". Is there a way to go from one to the other?

Comment: what result you need?

Comment: I need "Instrument: àßéçøö".  And I am getting "Instrument: Ã ÃÃ©Ã§Ã¸Ã¶"

Comment: @Sravan- I added information about the web api web.config file, if that helps?

Comment: Yes.  It did not answer my question.

Comment: by the way who opened a Bounty for the question?

Comment: @Sravan a fool that think a bounty would solve everything! :-)

Comment: gaining more attention from the community, I had the same problem as @DavidSetty

Comment: I will help you further with some source and link, Dont worry.

Comment: okay good to hear. but I don't know what is `gaining attention` :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133889/discussion-between-sravan-and-gianluca-ghettini).

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini, do you need any more explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Try below for encoding

`myAngApp1=document.getElementById("ItemSearch");
    var uri = myAngApp1.value;
    var place = encodeURIComponent(uri)`