# Response header not decoded correctly in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, http

I'm making a GET request to a webapi using the `$http()` AngularJS function

This is my GET request:

```
http://blahblahblah/api/.....&chartTitle=Instrument:%20%C3%A0%C3%9F%C3%A9%C3%A7%C3%B8%C3%B6
```

Response Headers as seen on the actual response:

```
chartTitle: Instrument: %C3%A0%C3%9F%C3%A9%C3%A7%C3%B8%C3%B6
```

When I retrieve the header, using headers("charttitle"), the value I receive is:

`Instrument: Ã ÃÃ©Ã§Ã¸Ã¶`

instead of the expected:

```
Instrument: %C3%A0%C3%9F%C3%A9%C3%A7%C3%B8%C3%B6
```

I tried setting UTF-8 encoding for the HTML page but I still get such string

Comment: try adding this,`$http.get("http://youraddress",
    {headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}`)

Comment: I tried but to no avail unfortunately

Comment: please add the code where you decoded the headers.

Comment: @Sravan please go here for the full more elaborate question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718364/utf-8-string-not-decoded-correctly-in-angularjs-spa    thanks!

Comment: pls check the same question, I posted an answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i think you using $http like below

$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     // Here you can access your all headers params
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     // Here you can access your all headers params
  });
```

Comment: could you please elaborate more? I don't get your solution, thanks