# .Net Core 3.1 API, Angular 9, Application-Error header bad encoding

Tags: angular, character-encoding, http-headers, asp.net-core-webapi

I set Application-Error header in .Net Core 3.1 API this way:

```
response.Headers.Add("Application-Error", message);
```

In a browser developer tools the message looks great:

[image]

but when I get this message in Angular, the national characters are bad:

```
if(error instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
  const applicationError = error.headers.get('Application-Error');
  console.log("msg: ", applicationError)
}
```

[image]

I don't know if the encoding error is on the .Net Core side or on the Angular side.

Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: do you use gzip compression?

Comment: No, I don't use it.

Comment: How do you add that? I could not add the message to response header since the Headers of HTTP doesn't accept non-ASCII characters.For your situation, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718364/utf-8-string-not-decoded-correctly-in-angularjs/41937240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with a help of link Xing Zou provided.

On .Net Core side I need to modify code to this:

```
response.Headers.Add("Application-Error", WebUtility.UrlEncode(message));
```

On Angular side I need to modife code to this:

```
let decoded = decodeURIComponent(applicationError).replace(/\+/g," ");
```